# Selection of inputCheckbox from list of items not working as expected

Tags: apex, visualforce

Following page is displayed on custom button on Case detail page.

On click on the page, it is supposed to display table of items with a checkbox.

Onclick of 'AddSpares' button; it is supposed to let us know which item is selected. Here no items is getting selected.

`Controller`

```
   public class AddSparesExtension {

    private final Case c;
    public List<Spares__c> spares {get;set;}
    public List<TSpares> tspares{get;set;}

    public AddSparesExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.c= (Case)stdController.getRecord();

        spares = [Select ID, Name, Case__c, Model__r.Name, Serial_Number__c From Spares__c Where Case__c = NULL];
        tspares = new List<TSpares>();
        for(Spares__c o: spares){
            tspares.add(new TSpares(o));
        }
    }

    public List<TSpares> getTSpares() {
        return tspares;
    }

    public void addTSpares(){
        Map<ID, Spares__c> sparesMap = new Map<ID, Spares__c>(spares);
        for(TSpares t:tspares){
                 system.debug('Is Selected--------------'+t.isSelected); 
        }
    }

    class TSpares{
       public ID idd {get;set;} 
       public String Name{get;set;} 
       public Id CaseX{get;set;} 
       public String ModelX{get;set;} 
       public String Serial_NumberX{get;set;} 
       public boolean isSelected{get;set;} 

        public TSpares(Spares__c sparesX){
           this.idd = sparesX.Id;
           this.Name = sparesX.Name;
           this.CaseX = sparesX.Case__c;
           this.ModelX = sparesX.Model__r.Name;
           this.Serial_NumberX = sparesX.Serial_Number__c;
           this.isSelected = false;
       }
    }
}
```

`VF Page`

```
<apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock title="Add Spares">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tspares}" var="item">
            <apex:column headerValue="Add">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!item.isSelected}" selected=""/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!item.Name}" headerValue="Spares Id"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!item.ModelX}" headerValue="Model"/>  
            <apex:column value="{!item.Serial_NumberX}" headerValue="Serial Number"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Spares" action="{!addTSpares}" immediate="true" oncomplete="closeAndRefreshParent();"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>

<script>
function closeAndRefreshParent(){
            window.opener.location.href = "/{!Case.Id}";
            window.top.close();
        }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works all right after removing `immediate="true"`

`immediate="true"` Documentation

**"A Boolean value that specifies whether the action associated with this component should happen immediately, without processing any validation rules associated with the fields on the page. If set to true, the action happens immediately and validation rules are skipped. If not specified, this value defaults to false."**

It looks like the observed behaviour is not expected & is a bug.